# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

**"При этом, считаю, что труд должен оплачиваться достойно, стоимость заказа – соответствовать предъявленным требованиям."**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *Хорошую ссылку на правило сделал @Авазбек Исманов*, но вывода не сделал:
   *ни по какому пункту правила **запятая после "при этом" не нужна!***

   [Я] **При этом считаю, что**... или **При этом** [я] **считаю, что**...
2. *Запятая перед подчинительным союзом "что"*, с помощью которого связаны между собой главное предложение и придаточные, думаю, *не вызывает сомнения* (как и запятая между ними).
3. Тире стоит на месте "пропуска" в сказуемом: стоимость заказа [должна] соответствовать...
4. Точку в конце предложения нужно "вынести" за кавычки.

   Правильно будет так:

   ***"При этом считаю, что труд должен оплачиваться достойно, стоимость заказа  — соответствовать предъявленным требованиям".***

Comment: Вообще непонятно, почему там кавычки стоят.

Comment: Не могу знать!  - по поводу кавычек. КАК было в вопросе - ТАК и отвечала (никто ведь не "правил")...  Возможно,  цитата? Мне непонятно только одно: ведь ответ был  - до моего - "принят"?! А вопрос-то - неплохой!

Answer (score 1):

Запятая была бы уместна при отсутствии союза "что".

*При этом труд должен оплачиваться достойно*... – запятых нет.

А теперь вставим вводное:

*При этом, считаю, труд должен оплачиваться достойно*...

Answer (score 0):

> [ПРИ ЭТОМ](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_642), союз и наречие
>   1. Союз. Синтаксические конструкции, присоединяемые союзом «при этом», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми.
>   Володя Яшкин, за ночь постаревший лет на двадцать и еще больше исхудавший, черный, со слезящимися, красными глазами, потряхивал головой, при этом все время что-то у него дребезжало в нагрудном кармане. В. Астафьев, Прокляты и убиты. Яковлев сел в кресло, закинул ногу на ногу, при этом обнаружились его красивые носки. В. Шукшин, Мнение.
>   ! После союза «при этом» запятая не ставится.
>   2. Наречие. Не требует постановки знаков препинания.
>   Он при этом крякнул и махнул рукой. И. Гончаров, Обыкновенная история. «Какой он, однако ж, жалкий!» – заметила при этом Нюта Смущенская. М. Салтыков-Щедрин, Для детского возраста.

Comment: Это всего-лишь цитата из словаря (уместная в данном случае), но не ответ на вопрос. Ведь спрашивали обо всех знаках препинания, а не только о выделении "при этом". Желательно дополнить ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Хотелось бы дополнить ответ @Niemand.

Возможны два отличающихся по смыслу варианта:

1. "При этом" относится к "считаю" ("при этом считаю")
2. "При этом" относится к "оплачиваться" ("при этом труд должен оплачиваться")

Предложение, приведенное в вопросе, построено так, что нет сомнения - это первый вариант. Имеем сложноподчиненное предложение, "считаю" - сказуемое в главном предложении. Запятая между "при этом" и "считаю" не нужна.

Но, возможно, автор вопроса подразумевал второй вариант - и поэтому выделил слово "считаю" запятыми. Если так, то надо убрать союз "что", и полагать слово "считаю" вводным. А стилистически еще лучше использовать вводное предложение "я считаю":

**При этом, я считаю, труд должен оплачиваться достойно...**